# How to print all text and HTML within a selector in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

```
<div id="test">
  ....
</div>
```

For debugging purposes, how to print out everything (html and text) within `div test`?

Comment: Getting a text of an element you can use '.text' method. page.find(:id, 'test').text.

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: Using default driver.